# Migration class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

What is migration class or migrations in Codeigniter.
Although I have gone through its documentation but it wasn't really clear to me, hence I am asking this question. Explanation with an example is required in layman terms.

While answering, Pl. don't use documentation's terms and examples. Try to keep it as simple as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations in frameworks are basically database queries in simple terms. The concept is generic and irrespective of any language.

During the development you keep adding new tables and alter some of the database entities, migration in frameworks help you to maintain that all. There are basically 2 basic parts (there can be a lot more).

- Up
- Down

Up is usually the change in database entity (that can be insert, delete, update etc.) while down is rollback of what you are doing with up.

When you are done with pushing the code on git (or any code control software that you use), the developers who pull the code, they just run the migrations so that you don't have to tell them explicitly what you changed in database.